# Command «npm run build» exited with 126 Vercel

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, build, vercel

I try to upload my website with Webpack to Vercel from repository but I get this Error on build time:

```
Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
Cloning completed: 2.089s
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 31.2.3
Installing dependencies...
up to date in 293ms
15 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
Running "npm run build"

sh: /vercel/path0/node_modules/.bin/webpack: Permission denied
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 126
```

Everything is okay when I type "npm run build" in VS Code terminal. I've tried deleting node_modules folder and installing webpack again and it didn't work. T_T

Answer (score 0):

Update the command with sudo. It seems in the vercel It required super user permission.

```
sudo npm run build
```

Or whatever command you use to execute vercel build, Just execute that with sudo.
eg.

```
sudo npm run dev
sudo npm run vercelbuild
```

and so on.

This will solve your problem.